# Suspend doesn't work in Debian / powers up after a second

Tags: debian, kernel, suspend

I already asked in #debian-next and [on the forum](https://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?t=157566), but thought I'll also ask here before switching back to Fedora.

Suspend does not work. When I use `systemctl suspend`, the workstation goes into suspend for about 1 second and then comes back.

I have no idea what could cause that.

I tried to disable some of those devices in `/proc/acpi/wakeup` (XHCn), didn't help.

I updated all firmware from https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/, also didn't help.

IIRC with Fedora 39 XfCE it worked, but I wasn't able to test it correctly because I was only able to flash a live image to an USB stick, where I experienced the same behavior.

The BIOS is up-to-date, it works like a charm on Windows. So, before I switch back to Fedora, if anyone has an idea how to get that working, any help/information/idea is very appreciated. I like Debian, but this is unfortunately a killer for me :/

dmesg: https://pastebin.com/VidzhNgB

Edit: I installed fedora for testing. I was wrong, I have the same problem there. So I am wondering what's wrong now. It was working like a charm, I can remember that. But … the only thing I changed are those RGB case FANs. I doubt those can interrupt suspend??

Comment: maybe check what settings you have in `mem_sleep` and `disk` files in /sys/power

Comment: cat mem_sleep shows: s2idle [deep] and cat disk shows: [platform] shutdown reboot suspend test_resume

Comment: i wonder if it's possible that your s3 doesn't work. Might be worth a try to see how s2idle behaves if it's one of those new CPUs, I think that would be setting kernel param default_mem_sleep to s2idle. And you may consider seeing about setting the default disk behavior to be "shutdown"

Comment: would be nice to get more easy to understand informations. "setting default disk behaviour to be shutdown" - where/how should i do that?

Comment: tested default_mem_sleep=s2idle, did nothing

Comment: Hibernation requires a RAM-sized, contiguous, swap area. Do you have one? Read `man free mkswap fallocate  filefrag swapon fstab`.

Comment: sorry, its not hibernate, its suspend

Comment: What is the result of `cat /sys/power/state`?  See also: [Linux Kernel Documentation: Power](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.18/admin-guide/pm/sleep-states.html)

Comment: freeze mem disk

Comment: Hey @OP, I've had grief with NVIDIA vcard drivers. Let me know if that's the case in Your HW setup.

Comment: No, nothing with nvidia. I got rid now of that gigabyte crap board, replaced it with an asrock and all works as expected. Linux + Gigabyte = bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a real solution, but the only way to get this fixed was to replace the mainboard with one from ASRock. Now everything works as expected.

Very sad that there was no other way.

Answer (score 0):

I Had the same problem (Lenovo Thinkpad z13), which was working well until before New Years using archlinux. So I found out that the kernel was updated, from 6.6.7 to 6.6.8 and further to 6.6.9. With 6.6.7 it suspend (s2idle) works well, with 6.6.8 and 6.6.9 it does not go to sleep.